Flex and Bison not creating header (.h) file
So for my final project, I need to write a parser using flex and bison. I have it downloaded to my PATH, and am able to run all the commands. Only problem is, when I run the below commands, the .y file doesnt create the .h header file that I need in my .l lexer file to link the two. My file names are lexer.l and parser.y and their details are below. My question is, what might be causing the header file to not be created?
Commands
flex lexer.l //<--- Build the lexer file
bison -d -t parser.y //<--- Build the bison file
gcc lex.yy.c //<--- Create the .yy.c file
.\a.exe //<--- Start the parse

lexer.l
/*
========================
=========F=L=E=X========
========================
-The lexer (.l) file is in charge of taking in a string and parsing it into TOKENS.
    It generates the lex.yy.c which is a bunch of complicated C code that is created
    through building our lexer file.
*/

/* =====HEADERS=====*/
%{
   #include "parser.tab.h"
%}
/*==========REGULAR=EXPRESSIONS+=========*/



/*==========RULES===========*/

%%

[0-9]+ { yylval.num = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
\n { return EOL; }
. {}

%%
  
/*==========C=FUNCTIONS==========*/

yywrap() {}

parser.y
%{

%}

/* ==========TOKEN=TYPES==========*/

%union {
    int num;
    char sym;
}

/* ===========DEFINE=OUR=TOKENS========== */

%token EOL
%token PLUS
%token<num> NUMBER
%type<num> exp

/* ==========GRAMMAR========== */
%%

input: 
    exp EOL { printf("%d\n", $1); }
|   EOL;

exp: 
    NUMBER { $$ = $1 }
|   exp PLUS exp { $$ = $1 + $3; }
;

%%

int main() {
    yyparse();

    return 0; // Return 0 on successful execution
}

File Structure

Ive been thinking it was being caused because I was using the wrong commands, but it seems theres really only one way to do it. I should be able to just run
bison -d parser.y
Ive thought that it could be caused by the bison file not being valid, but I copied it from a tutorial here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFRxWtRibC8

There is no #include statement in your lexer.l file that needs any .h file.

@user207421 Correct I dont have that and ill add that so its not confusing, but the command that gets run on the parser.y should create a header file but doesnt and that is the issue

How can it possibly be the issue when you don't have code that relies on it? What issue?

Bison creates the header file you need if you give it the -d option, but to use it in your .l file, you'll need an #include there:
/* =====HEADERS=====*/
%{
#include "parser.tab.h"
%}

You'll also need to compile the parser.tab.c file that bison creates:
gcc parser.tab.c lex.yy.c

Note that the names used for the generated files by bison are by default based on the base name of the .y file you give it.  If you're following a yacc tutorial it will instead use the filenames y.tab.h and y.tab.c.  If you give bison a -y flag, it will generate those files (-y meaning "yacc compatibility mode") instead

I added the #include in my lexer file and added the parser.tab.c to my command, but my problem is that when I run "bison -d parser.y", it doesnt create the header file I need.

Looks like you're not getting anything out of bison.  There are a variety of reasons that might happen -- bison not installed correctly, errors in the .y file, running out of disk space -- but all of those should give some kind of error message when you run "bison -d parser.y"

Thanks for the comment! I scrolled up on what bison would output to my console and it looked like it was having a problem accessing my gnu file because it was stored in a location where the file had spaces (Program Files (x86). I think that was causing my environment variables to not work.

After checking the output that I was getting from bison (I originally thought it was supposed to output a bunch of code), my GNUwin32 file was stored in "Program Files (x86). This was causing my parser to not recognize the location because of the spaces in the file name. Thanks to @ChrisDodd for telling me to check my output!
